# How to disable validation on control in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net

**Software**:

*ASP.NET Application. Visual Studio 2013.*

**Scenario**:

I have three button: **email**, **start project** and **clear**. When I click on the **start project** button, it validates the user's input automatically. When I click **clear** button, it should clear any user's input.

My problem is, when I click on the **clear** button, it is trying to **validate** the user's input.

**Question**:

When I click on the clear button, How can I disable this validation & enable again when I click submit button?

**Code sample:**

```
<input type="email"  runat="server" id="email"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnStartProject" runat="server" Text="Start project" 
            OnClick="btnStartProject_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" OnClick="btnClear_Click" Text="Clear" 
            EnableClientScript="False" 
            CausesValidation="False" />
```

Comment: remove EnableClientSideScript="False" on your button. That belongs on the validator control.

Comment: I have removed it but it did not help.

Comment: Actually, I was using reset input type before but it had not worked. I tried again and now it is working. I do not need to disable validation on email input type by coding. The following button clears every field:

    <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I am putting my comment as an answer for this case. It might be helpful for future readers)*

It is not neccessary, to disable the validation on the email button by custom coding. Changing the input type of the clear button to `reset` has solved my problem: `<input type="reset" value="Clear"/>`